# How can I pass my remote username and password directly into hg outgoing?

Tags: mercurial

I have a repository where I want to undo all local commits on my branch since the most recent commit pulled down. I do not want to save any work.

After doing some research I found the following on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/89064/how-do-i-remove-outgoing-changesets-in-mercurial-hg):

```
hg --config "extensions.strip = " strip "roots(outgoing())"
```

> Note that I have added `--config "extensions.strip = "` because I do not have the strip extension enabled.

After executing this command it then appears to already know my remote username (which is not in my mercurial.ini) and prompts for my remote password - this then appears to function exactly as I want it to.

My question is how does it know my username already if it is not stored in my mercurial.ini? And more importantly how can I pass both my username and password directly into my command so I could give a different username and have it also not prompt me for the password?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have anything under `[auth]` section in mercurial.ini?

Comment: @Arun it is all commented out except for lines in square braces

Comment: Do you mind pasting your mercurial.ini? Mine is here: https://bitbucket.org/carun/dot-files/src/tip/mercurial.ini#lines-11 and with `[auth]` section commented, THG prompts me for username and password. Which hg client are you using and which OS are you on?

Comment: @Arun sure - here is my mercurial.ini: https://pastebin.com/rcbDUHb1
I am just using a command prompt window in Windows 10

Comment: Using strip is only going to work if you are dealing with un-pushed changesets. If you strip something which was pushed already eventually it will get pulled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the repo's `.hg/hgrc` to confirm if it doesn't have any credential? If you have cloned using your username (eg: `http://username:password@ip:port/reponame`), it will stay in the repo's config.

You can create a new named path in `.hg/hgrc` and pass it to `"roots(outgoing(newpath))"`. That will do what you are expecting.

Comment: That is how I cloned it and yes, there are credentials in that file. So how can I pass potentially different ones into hg strip?

Comment: hg strip doesn't take usernames as input as strip operates only on local repo. The `outgoing` revset is the one that triggers the query to remote. You can update the username in `.hg/hgrc` for it to use.

Comment: Ah ok - so there is no way to pass a username and password directly into outgoing?

Comment: You can create a new named path in `.hg/hgrc` and pass it to `"roots(outgoing(newpath))"`

Comment: It's not an applicable answer for me unfortunately as I want to pass them directly into the command, In a couple of days, if I receive no more answers I will mark yours as answering my question